# Как сохранить запись в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

```
 <?php
 /* @var $this MyGalleryController */
 /* @var $model MyGallery */
 /* @var $form CActiveForm */
 ?>
<div class="form">
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'my-gallery-form',

    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'

    ),

    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
));
?>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'description', array('size' => 60,    'maxlength' => 255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'description'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'img_url'); ?>
    <div id="dropZed" class="dropzone"></div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'img_url'); ?>
  </div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Создать' : 'Сохранить', array(
        'name'=>'submit', 'id' => 'sb-all'
    )); ?>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        var dzone = new Dropzone("#dropZed", {
            paramName: "file",
            url: "/admin/MyGallery/ImagesUpload",
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            init: function() {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#sb-all");
                dzone = this; // closure

                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    dzone.processQueue();
                });
            }
        });
            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    });;
</script>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

тут контроллер

```
public function actionImagesUpload(){
        $tml_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tml_name, '/img/upload/' . '13' . $name);
    return $name;
}
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new MyGallery;
    if (isset($_POST['MyGallery'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['MyGallery'];
        $model->img_url = MyGalleryController::actionImagesUpload();
        if ($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
   }
```

`MyGalleryController::actionImagesUpload()` - по идет возвращается $name - а в $name - лежит `$_FILES['file']['name]` но выходит ошибка undefined index file. Как так ?

Comment: Ах да забыл, решил установить dropzone на yii/

Comment: Там может быть массив файлов, в этом случае структура будет немного другой. В любом случае используйте CUploadedFile.

Comment: Запустите debug метода `actionImageUpload()` или проверьте, что лежит в массиве `$_FILES` при помощи функций `print_r($_FILES);` или `var_dump($_FILES);`